# Highlighting text in commandline java

Tags: java, unix, command-line, calendar, highlight

I have an assignment to recreate the unix cal program, fairly straightforward except for one part. On the current day, it highlights the number. I have no idea how to do this. Any idea on how to do it in Java?

Image:

[image: Calender]

Comment: doesn't that depend on the terminal you're using? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84078/highlighting-text-in-shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ANSI color codes
>
> The color of the prompt is set by expanding the escape sequence
>   “\e[sm”, where s is a semicolon-delimited list of ANSI color codes:
>   “\e[31;44;1m” would set the foreground color to red, the background to
>   blue, and the font in bold face; (The “\e” is the ASCII Escape
>   character. Don’t forget to terminate the sequence with the “m”
>   character.)
>
> Binary sequences in the environment variables need to be set off by
>   indicators that they have zero width, or else the shell won’t
>   calculate correctly the width of the prompt. Bash encases such things
>   with slash-brackets “[ .. ]”, whereas Tcsh uses percent-brace “%{ ..
>   %}”.

```
The codes:
0   restore default color
1   brighter
2   dimmer
4   underlined text
5   flashing text
7   reverse video

            black   red     green   yellow  blue    purple  cyan    white
foreground  30      31      32      33      34      35      36      37
background  40      41      42      43      44      45      46      47
```

from http://zipcon.net/~swhite/docs/computers/linux/shell_prompts.html

So in order to do this through Java, you need to set

`System.out.println(characterCode + character);`

where `String characterCode = "\033[31;44;1m";` and `char character = 'A';`

and you would get an `A` with foreground color set to red, the background to blue, and the font in bold...

---

EDIT : Results of a test in Xubuntu

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char character = 'A';
    String characterCode;
    for (int foreground = 30; foreground < 38; foreground++) {
        for (int background = 40; background < 48; background++) {
            characterCode = "\033[" + foreground + ";" + background + ";1m";
            System.out.print(characterCode + character);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

[image: code result]

Comment: Yeah I couldn't get that to work. Good source though. My compiler tells me that it can't escape the \e.

Comment: I didn't really test it, so I'm sure it would require some tinkering... I'm actually curious about it :) I'll switch to linux and check how it would work...

Comment: Okay, so I tried it and it worked with `String characterCode = "\033[31;44;1m";`. I tried it in Ubuntu Terminal :)

Comment: This worked on my Mac terminal (zsh). Great answer

Comment: Worked well for me. Thanks a lot!